# LabVIEW library .NET cannot be connected

Tags: labview

Please, Could someone help me with the `.NET Framework` connectivity with `LabVIEW`. I have installed `.NET 4` Fremework and when Im connecting it to the `LabVIEW` it shows me an `error 1172` that it cannot connect the library. 
Thank you for your response.

Comment: Which environment owns the process? Are you trying to call into LabVIEW from a .NET application, or are you trying to call into .NET from a LabVIEW application?

Answer (score 1):

Error code 1172... go to menu item Help >> Explain Error... get this explanation:

*LabVIEW:  A .NET exception occurred in an external assembly. For information about correcting this error, copy the following exception (in bold), and search the Microsoft Developer Network (MSDN) Web site or the Web for a possible explanation.*

So there's an exception being thrown on the .NET side. The error cluster that you're getting back should have details about exactly what that exception is. You'll have to read the .NET documentation about your library to go any further.